# Laravel skip directory from framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am facing a problem, the mapping of my site looks like this:

```
- app
- bootstrap
- public_html
  - archives
  - css
  - js
  index.php
- vendor
composer.json
etc...
```

My .htaccess is located in `public_html`. I want to skip the directory `public_html/archives` from the whole framework. How would I do that? I want the route `mysite.com/archives` to be accessible outside Laravel.

Edit:
Here is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/public/archives/" <--- ADDED!
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Because with the default `.htaccess` Laravel doesn't run on requests to files or directories that actually exist.

Comment: I have tried a lot of things with the .htaccess file, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Displee - please share the content of your `.htaccess` file. Have you made in changes to the file?

Comment: I have added my htaccess file to the main post, sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, Laravel won't process any files or directories that exist because of the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

First, take this rule out of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/public/archives/"
```

Then, after the `RewriteEngine On` line, you need to add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^archives/?$ - [PT]
```

So your .htaccess file will look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^archives/?$ - [PT]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Alternatively, you can just add the following line before `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/archives/?.*$
```